# Request method 'GET' not supported,Method Not Allowed, status=405

Tags: spring-boot

`Request method 'GET' not supported, Method Not Allowed 405()`

When I use @DeleteMapping in my controller class I Got the above type of error First I did not use 'path' the in my DeleteMapping I directly provide my path, Then I got the same error Why getting this type of error. Plz, mention what is the main reason for this type of error and what is the solution Controller.java

```
package com.main.AngBoot.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.main.AngBoot.bean.Product;
import com.main.AngBoot.service.ProductHardcodedService;

@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductHardcodedService prodService;
    @GetMapping("/users/{productname}/prodct")
    public List<Product> getAllProducts(@PathVariable String productname){
        return prodService.findAll();
        
    }
    @DeleteMapping(path="/users/{productname}/prodct/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteProduct(@PathVariable String productname,
            @PathVariable long id){
        Product product = prodService.deleteById(id);
        if (product != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

}
```

> i get this  error in my chrome browser
> [image]

> I got same error on postman
> [image]

Comment: Well, because you shouldn't send an HTTP GET message to the @DeleteMapping endpoint. Also, please don't include your own texts as a `citation`.

Comment: Postman error is different. Configure your cors propertly.

Answer (score 2):

```
@DeleteMapping(path="/users/{productname}/prodct/{id}")
```

Here you are using a `@DeleteMapping`, which means, that you are supposed to send an `HTTP DELETE` request for this endpoint. You are getting `Method Not Allowed` because you are sending an `HTTP GET` request which you are not allowed to do, since you are not mapping method annotated with `@DeleteMapping` for the `HTTP GET` message.

Comment: plz tell me how to solve this type of error,where make changes in my code,I donot understand,bucz I am new to webservice

Comment: Send HTTP Delete request instead Get request

Comment: How to send Delete Request instead Get request,I create delete service in  another service class

Comment: @nilnil How you hit your endpoint ? Like postman or consumes by another service ?

Comment: See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kmLoiOCO3A)